# Compile .dtx into .sty for TexPad?

Tags: packages, dtx, texpad

I need to use the accessibility package with my TexPad application for MacOS, but the package includes both .dtx and .ins files. When I try to compile the .dtx file with pdfLaTeX in TexPad to generate an .sty, I get an error message ("Emergency stop."). How can I compile the .dtx to generate an .sty?

Comment: you must compile the ins-file (with latex or tex normally) while the dtx is beside it. Then it will unpack it. But be aware that they use some quite experimental stuff in the package and I have no idea if this works with texpad.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why don't  you simply install it with `TeX Live Utility`?

Comment: I tried to combine the ins and dtx file side-by-side but I get an "Emergency Stop" error. I'm not sure how to fix this?

And I've never used TeX Live Utility?

Comment: download this file http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/axessibility.tar.lzma Then find an application that can unpack lzma and tar files and unpack first the lzma and then the tar in it. Then you should find a sty in the folder.  But perhaps you should first try their cloud typesetter, they claim here that it has all packages https://www.texpad.com/docs/tutorials/tex/typesetters/texpadtex/package-coverage